# Error about a missing file when excecuting the example code of the cDMN python module

Tags: python, rule-engine, expert-system, bpmn.io, dmn

i am not an experienced programmer and i need to create an expert system for a project. I opted for the cDMN python module to do so. My first step was to follow the example on the [documentation](https://cdmn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/DMN_guide.html) site.

I recieved a couple warnings when printing the inputs and outputs, that i assumed not being very problematic for the execution:

```
INFO: No function glossary table found.
INFO: No relation glossary table found.
WARNING: Token 'NOT' multiply defined
WARNING: Token 'YES' multiply defined
WARNING: Token 'NO' multiply defined
WARNING: Token 'ABS' multiply defined
WARNING: Token 'MIN' multiply defined
WARNING: Token 'MAX' multiply defined
```

The real problem appears when i try to interact with the DMN model, setting values goes fine but Model expansion and Propagation give me the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c://Desktop/cdmn test.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(spec.model_expand().getvalue())
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\cdmn\API.py", line 282, in model_expand
    with open('/tmp/idp_temp.txt', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') \
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/idp_temp.txt'
```

I don't really get it, i'm not trying to do something complicated, just trying to run the example and this makes me think that something went wrong when installing the module. I don't know if there are experienced people in this matter and hope to reach the right people. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and solved it this way:

- Create folder tmp (within the virtual environment) and copy the absolute path
- Convert backslash `\` in this absolute path to `/` forward slash
- Go to your venv folder and look for `cdmn-.../API.py`
- Search and replace `'/tmp/idp_temp.txt'` with `'ABSOLUTE_URL/idp_temp.txt'`